# How to send and receive file with Java RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, file, rabbitmq, messaging

How to send file with Java RabbitMQ?
Especially using message converter.

I'm using Spring Framework, can send String or ArrayList but can't send File. I'm only use `convertAndSend` and `convertAndReceive` to send File but get :

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I don't know how to use message converter. The code from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/helloworld/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/helloworld/async) and change some class :

HelloWorldHandler.java

```
package org.springframework.amqp.helloworld.async;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;

public class HelloWorldHandler {

    public void handleMessage(File message) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(message));
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
}
```

ProducerConfiguration.java

```
package org.springframework.amqp.helloworld.async;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;

@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {

    protected final String helloWorldQueueName = "hello.world.queue";

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey(this.helloWorldQueueName);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("x.x.x.x");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("username");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduledProducer scheduledProducer() {
        return new ScheduledProducer();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }


    static class ScheduledProducer {

        @Autowired
        private volatile RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

        private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
        public void sendMessage() {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(new File("test.txt"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Convert file byte data in base64 encoded string. Base64 encoding is standard to convert byte data to string and vice-versa,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the file content into byte array and send the byte[] as below.

```
byte[] fileData = // get content from file as byte[]  [Refer Here][1]
String fileType  = // get file type from file

Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(fileData).setHeader("ContentType", fileType).build();

rabbitTemplate.send("exchnage name", "routing key", message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @manmay. But, is it possible for using MessageConverter? If yes, can you tell me the implementation, because I'm already googling about it but can't find the works one ^^

Comment: You can write your own converter by implementing the interface MessageConverter. Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html (Section : 3.6 Message Converters)

Comment: if i use the code you give to send file, how I convert it from message to file in consumer side? thanks before, @manmay

Comment: On the consumer side you will get the message body as byte[] then you can handle it as per your requirement.

Comment: then, how can I know file type and file name in consumer side?

Comment: I see then set the file type as header on the producer side while publishing the message. like : Header Name : fileType & Header Value : text . Updated the example in the answer above.